# Deploying a Rails 5 app to EC2- RDS DB Instance connectivity error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created DB instance and gone through the config process of aws rds instance as per the documentation.
created an instance of db successfully.
also changed the connection params in database.yml accordingly.
I ran the following commands in ngnix server installed on ubuntu 16.04 at aws and also rebooted the db instance several times.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```

and db created successfully
and then ran

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

and database migrated successfully.
an then ran the command 
sudo service nginx restart
after all of the process 
when I am visiting my app its says

> ```
> PG::ConnectionBad
> could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP
> connections on port 5432?
> ```

here is my database.yml

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: ups_developement_db
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
production:
  host: dbcustom.cjocvmnblsa4.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  database: ups_db
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  port: 5432
  username: dbmasteruser
  password: dbmasterPassword
```

I am open to provide any kind of information required.
Thanks a lot for your time and solution in advance

Comment: here is the IP address of my app   http://18.219.80.84/

Comment: I think you can check your RDS security group permission. Because application instance can’t connect with RDS instance. It’s my guess.

Comment: Security group permission is enabled on RDS is set to "all traffic"

Comment: I saw that other peoples are having same problem
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258529/rds-logging-not-appearing-for-postgresql]

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certain that you have not configured the security groups on the RDS instance correctly.

Log into your EC2 and issue the command

```
telnet <rds hostname> 5432
```

You should see something like

```
Trying 10.1.1.2...
Connected to 10.1.1.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

which means that TCP can flow between your EC2 and your RDS.

If not, you need to permit your EC2 to connect to your RDS instance by adding the correct security group configuration.

Comment: I just did it 
telnet dbcustom.cjocvmnblsa4.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com 5432

Trying 172.31.34.251...
Connected to ec2-18-222-90-240.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: When I tried  **psql -h dbcustom.cjocvmnblsa4.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U dbmasteruser
Password for user dbmasteruser:**
 
psql: FATAL:  database "dbmasteruser" does not exist

Comment: is that something that generate a clue?

Answer (score 0):

You should create Environment variables in your AWS RDS instance you should use them in your rails app config file. [Check here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby.rds.html)

database.yml should look like this

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```